# rake db:schema:dump in cmd it is not generating schema.rb file in database folder

Tags: schema, rake

I m new to ruby on rails when I try to run rake `db:schema:dump` in cmd it is not generating `schema.rb` file in database folder

> C:\Users\ACK\SITES\simple_cms>rake db:schema:dump --trace
>   ** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
>   ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>   ** Execute environment
>   ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
>   ** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
>   ** Execute rails_env
>   ** Execute db:load_config rake aborted! couldn't parse YAML at line 19 column 2 C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in`parse_stream'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:119:in `parse'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:106:in`load'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/configu
>   ration.rb:106:in `database_configuration'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railtie
>   .rb:68:in`block (2 levels) in '
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_
>   load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_
>   load_hooks.rb:36:in`execute_hook'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_
>   load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_
>   load_hooks.rb:42:in`each'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_
>   load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb
>   :2190:in`'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railtie
>   s/databases.rake:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in`
>   call'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in
>   `block in execute'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in`
>   each'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in
>   `execut e'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in`
>   block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in`
>   invoke
>   _with_call_chain' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in
>   `block in invoke_prerequisites'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in`
>   each'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in
>   `invoke
>   _prerequisites' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in`
>   block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in`
>   invoke
>   _with_call_chain' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in
>   `invoke '
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in`
>   invoke_task'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in
>   `block (2 levels) in top_level'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in`
>    each'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in
>   `block in top_level'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in`
>   standard_exception_handling'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in
>   `top_level'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in`
>    block in run'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in`
>    run' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in
>   `
>
> > ' C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `load' C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in`' Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump => db:load_config
>
> C:\Users\ACK\SITES\simple_cms>

Comment: You have something broken in `database.yml`

Comment: development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: simple_cms
  password:12345
  host: localhost

Comment: update your question text instead

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your password in your database.yml file is a string, as in not all numbers. For example, 321 would pull an error, b321 would work.

At least as my of this writing (4.21.12), different program updates get made asynchronously and things can break since they're talking to each other differently.